# How to track from which site user came from to my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to store url of user's referral website after sucessfull registration. In this case I can't use `request.referer` because user can visit few pages on my website before registration. But I need previous website url, for example `http://google.com` or `http://facebook.com/somepage_id` or whatever. I know that Google Analytics or Intercome can collect this data but I want something simple. Preferably without external APIs or libraries if this possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is ruby gem called '**ahoy**', which can be used for this.

When someone visits your website, Ahoy creates a visit with lots of useful information.

- traffic source - referrer, referring domain, landing page, search
  keyword
- location - country, region, and city
- technology - browser, OS, and device type
- utm parameters - source, medium, term, content, campaign

Please find the link for more information,
[Ahoy](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy)

Answer (score 1):

When user reach your site create `UserSession` which will store `request.referer` also it has `user_id`. And during registration bind `UserSession` to created `User` by filling `user_id`. In this case you will get site from which user came + you can get some additional info from `UserSession`(user-agent, date, visited pages and etc.)